Show that $A[[X]]\cong A^\mathbb{N}$ as a topological group for the $(\mathfrak{m}, X)$-adic topology.
Let $A$ be a commutative, unital ring and $\mathfrak{m}$ be an ideal of $A$. Show that if $A$ is Hausdorff and complete for the $\mathfrak{m}$-adic topology then the ring of formal power series $A[[X]]$ with the $(\mathfrak{m}, X)$-adic topology is isomorphic as a topological group to $A^\mathbb{N}$.
I can show that they are isomorphic as groups but I can't construct a homeomorphism.

Presumably you have found an isomorphism that you want to show is a homeomorphism? What have you tried?

@arkeet The isomorphism is the most obvious one: matching the coefficient of $X^i$ to the "ith coordinate" of an element in $A^\mathbb{N}$. I wanted to conclude by showing that this is a strict morphism mapping $(\mathfrak{m}, X)^n$ of $A[[X]]$ to $(\mathfrak{m}^n)^\mathbb{N}$ of $A^\mathbb{N}$ but I don't know how to go about it. The book says to use the topology of pointwise convergence but I can't figure out how to use that exactly.
